# VS Code Python 3- Hover over variable types

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

[Python in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1rfH.png)

When I hover over some variables I get this showing. How do I make sense of this? Does it mean that the *value* variable has an `int` and a `float` type? Unfortunately I don't have the reputation to display the image directly on the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the variable can be either `int` or `float` type depends on the runtime environment.